# Why did Tywin ride a horse into court?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

When Tywin receives the title of the Hand at the end of the second season, why did he ride a horse into the halls just to receive the pin and go away?

Is it that way in the books as well?

Comment: Ned Stark did the same, when he rode along the throne room to take control of the Iron Throne, after Jaime had killed Aerys. Presumably it is a symbolic act of taking charge.

Comment: @TLP: I find it very different to do that after conquering the city, and doing that in times of essentially peace.

Comment: I think the motivations were different. Ned had just left a battle, had no idea what he would find in the throne room, and wanted to be able to fight or escape on horseback. Tywin did not necessarily know or care about Ned's ride -- he was doing it as a not very subtle demonstration that he was in charge, because under normal circumstances *no one* is allowed to ride a horse into the throne room.

Comment: Let us not forget the load of dung that Tywin's horse dumped in the middle of the throne room, as depicted in the book.

Comment: It's a sign he doesn't give a damn about anyone else's authority

Answer (score 9):

This scene does take place in the book in basically the same manner in Sansa's last (8th) chapter of *A Clash of Kings*:

> He rode his warhorse down the length of the hall and dismounted before the Iron Throne. Sansa had never seen such armor; all burnished red steel, inlaid with golden scrollwork and ornamentation. His rondels were sunbursts, the roaring lion that crowned his helm had ruby eyes,
>   and a lioness on each shoulder fastened a cloth-of-gold cloak so long and heavy that it draped the hindquarters of his charger. Even the horse’s armor was gilded, and his bardings were shimmering crimson silk emblazoned with the lion of Lannister.
>
> The Lord of Casterly Rock made such an impressive figure that it was a shock when his destrier dropped a load of dung right at the base of the throne. Joffrey had to step gingerly around it as he descended to embrace his grandfather and proclaim him Savior of the City.

And as pointed out in the comments, we know Eddard did the same thing after the Sack of King's Landing based on Jaime's recollection of it in his 6th Chapter in *A Storm of Swords*:

> He remembered Eddard Stark, riding the length of Aerys’s throne room wrapped in silence.

As to why he did this, we can't be sure as there's no chapter from his perspective, but it could be because of tradition as the above would suggest (though that would be strange as Eddard arrived after the Lannisters had already sacked the city), or it could simply be a lack of interest in what less important people think of him as he often shows:

- Talking over Mace Tyrell whenever he starts brown-nosing him <sub>(S04E06 - The Laws of Gods and Men)</sub>
- Sending Joffrey to bed when he says Tywin was afraid of Aerys in a small council meeting <sub>(Tyrion's 6th Chapter, A Storm of Swords)</sub>

Comment: As I wrote to TLP in the comments, I find a big difference in doing that after conquering the city, and doing that in a peaceful manner. Tywin did not seize the control from his grandson in the same manner that Stark did from Jaime/Aerys.

Comment: Also in the book he dismounts when he reaches the king, in the series he doesn't. Someone hands him the pin, he bows slightly from his horse, turns around and goes outside.

Comment: (Also, the sending Joffery to bed also occurred on the show's 3rd finale. Charles Dance acting was great in that scene, as in his other scenes with the young Jack Gleeson (and as a side side note, his scenes with Maisie Williams in the second season were more than amazing).)

Answer (score 4):

Isn't there a chivalric tradition in Britain that the King's Champion is allowed to ride into the throne room (or wherever the court is gathered)? I seem to remember reading something of the kind.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Could you please provide some more information to your suggestion so that the OP can make a determination as to whether this is the story they are looking for?  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting! I'm not sure if it's what you're thinking of, but I found this: "[In centuries past the King’s Champion would ride into the Coronation Banquet in Westminster Hall and throw down his gauntlet three times in a challenge to anyone that would deny the new monarch](http://theenchantedmanor.com/tag/the-kings-dining-room-at-windsor-castle/)" - could have been part of the inspiration, and it's an obvious way to make an impressive show of strength

Comment: @user568458: and it would be particularly cool as we have only seen _two_ champions riding down that hall. So we can guess we're up to one more.